# Constructing a pair with an rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

In this:

```
    vector<pair<string,int>> vp;
    string s;
    int i;
    while(cin>>s>>i) vp.push_back({s,i});
```

I'm curious about the last line. The pair is constructed in the call to `push_back`, therefore it is moved, not copied, correct?

If it had instead been written as this:

```
    vector<pair<string,int>> vp;
    string s= ...;
    int i= ...;
    pair<string,int> p{s,i};
    vp.push_back(p);
```

While the construction of the pair involves the same resources, now the pair is named, `p`, therefore it is no longer an rvalue and therefore move semantics are no longer used, and therefore this is pass by value, causing a copy to be made, right?

This implies to me that where possible, constructing objects inside arg lists is a performance improvement; can anyone verify?

Comment: Depends on compiler optimizations.

Comment: second example does push one and same std::pair, with empty std::string and unknown / random int - correct?

Comment: @Nick true they are empty in this case (this code is from the C++ faq) but i'm concerned more with the push_back semantics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The pair is constructed in the call to `push_back`, therefore it is moved, not copied, correct?

The temporary pair is constructed and then bound to the rvalue reference argument of `push_back`. It is then moved from that argument into the `vector`.

```
vp.push_back({s,i});
```

is equivalent to:

```
vp.push_back(std::pair<std::string, int>{s, i});
```

which is roughly equivalent to:

```
std::pair<std::string, int> p{s, i};
vp.push_back(std::move(p));
```

You don't *need* a temporary to use the rvalue reference overload.

Your second code example:

```
pair<string,int> p{s,i};
vp.push_back(p);
```

does copy instead of move, yes. Note that either way, we're still copying `s` into the pair (either the temporary or `p`). So an even better approach would be to move `s` into the temporary as well:

```
vp.push_back({std::move(s), i});
```

or to not even have the intermediate pair to begin with:

```
vp.emplace_back(std::move(s), i);
```

> This implies to me that where possible, constructing objects inside arg lists is a performance improvement; can anyone verify?

*Moving* is a performance improvement, but you can always `std::move()` an argument into a function - it doesn't need to be a temporary. Constructing inside the arg list affects when the moved-from object's destructor gets called, nothing more.

Comment: what happens to `p` after `std::move(p)` ?

Comment: @johnbakers then p will be in a valid but undefined state

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Constructing object inside arg list is an improvement.

However think a while. `int` can not be moved. It is a copy. Generally `std::string` will be moved and this will safe one `malloc` / `new` call.

If all this does not affect readability - go for it. Else, in most cases it will not be such a big improvement I believe.

I would suggest one more "way"

```
std::pair<std::string,int> p{s,i};
vp.push_back(std::move(p));
```

I would suggest even one more "way"

```
vp.emplace_back(std::move(s), i);
```

**Update** - I removed `cin` part as it was removed in the question.

Comment: why -1 ? because of `malloc()` ?

Comment: Not malloc of course. And not neccessarily save anything.

Comment: Depending of library, new is malloc under the hood. If string is empty or sso, there will be no savings at all. if string is huge, you will avoid new / malloc and memcpy / memmove.